# Writing ( and ) in a regex doesn't work

Tags: c#

Can you help me to write this small Regex for this which get text between `('` & `')`

```
('SomeText')   = > SomeText
('Some')Text')   = > Some')Text
('Some'Text')   = > Some'Text
```

I tried `('(.*)')` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/xT3jX1/1)?

```
\('(.*)'\)
```

You need to escape `(` and `)` since those are reserved in Regex. So every time you encounter a `(` or a `)` which you want to evaluate as a literal, you need to escape them.

Comment: its good but does not extract text between this ... it give whole values like this ('SomeText')

Comment: No, it doesn't. Did you see the link? See what is in the first capture.

Comment: one small help more  how can I do this too ((0)) => 0, ((1)) => 1

Comment: You need to escape `(` and `)` since those are regex characters. So you need `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: if you dont mind can you share.What will be final regex for this?

Comment: Come on, this is not a code writing service. Give it a try, and if it doesn't work, you come here.

Comment: Where did the `'` come from? Did you read my comment how to escape?

Comment: seems you edited your last comment :) .. but I got your point ... `@"\(\((.*)\)\)" `

Answer (score 1):

A RegEx-free solution:

```
string ExtractString(string s, string tag) {
     var startTag = "(" + tag + ")";
     int startIndex = s.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length;
     int endIndex = s.IndexOf("(/" + tag + ")", startIndex);
     return s.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
}
```

Or With

```
  Regex regex = new Regex("<(>(.*)</)>");
  var v = regex.Match("morenonxmldata<(>0002<)>morenonxmldata");
  string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```